# Dropdown menu in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dropdown</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Article<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>Technology</li>
<li>Technology 2</li>
<li>Technology 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this code is not working properly on my Browser(firefox),the dropdown-list is not apearing when I click the button.. Please help

Comment: If you'd create a working fiddle example of your problem if would be easier to check for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Article
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Technology 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Technology 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Technology 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Bootstrap, always make sure that **head** section contains:

1. jquery script
2. bootstrap javascript
3. bootstrap css file

This has to be the order, otherwise it won't work.
D Sai Krishna's code (especially first three rows) is how it is supposed to be. I always find it better to use external link to .js and .css files than to use local files. To conclude, in **head** section paste external links (these one's are current as of this writing):

```
    1. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   //This will initialize jQuery and enable it to work properly//

    2. <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   //This will implement Javascript whenever Bootstrap is being used (if applicable). //

    3. <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">   //This will enable Bootstrap styles to be applied to your HTML//
```

For reference, visit **W3schools.com/bootstrap** where you can find how to implement above mentioned lines and where. You will also find current external links of bootstrap .js and .css